# Are there any books about implementing network data encryption using OpenSSL's cryptolib?

Tags: linux, encryption, openssl

Like in the title, I want to encrypt data, which is sent over network. Because I 
decided to use [TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) and/or [SCTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_Control_Transmission_Protocol) protocols I cannot use SSL/TLS. That's why I want 
to implement my own solution based on the SSL idea. Two peers will exchange symmetric 
algorithm's key (AES) using an asymmetric algorithm (RSA) first and then continue 
communication encrypting data using the symmetric algorithm.

I develop my application in C++ for Linux. The problem is that I'm new to data 
encryption, I had only few very general lectures at university about network 
security... I'll have more about this next year.

So far I figured out, that OpenSSL provides the sub-library libcrypto, which has 
everything I need :) But the manual pages aren't too helpful, 
especially for new users like me...

Can you recommend me any book or network resources about OpenSSL and cryptography
for programmers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Network security with OpenSSL](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596002701)
2. [OpenSSL: Open Source, Transport Layer Security, C (Programming Language), Cryptography, Unix-Like, Solaris (Operating System), Linux, Mac OS X, RSA Security](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/6130344767)
3. [Applied Cryptography: Protocols, Algorithms, and Source Code in C](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471117099)
4. [Related stuff](http://www.openssl.org/related/)

Recommending the first one (O'Reilly).

Comment: Clicked the link for that second book, and it's astounding.  Just.. wow.

Comment: Careful, they might include stackoverflow articles in the next edition.

Answer (score 0):

*Because I decided to use TCP and/or SCTP protocols I cannot use SSL/TLS.*

This is a non-sequiter.  There is nothing stopping you from using TLS (SSL) over TCP or SCTP - in fact TLS is almost always running over TCP.